# SharePoint-Online Webpart Zone Index

Tags: sharepoint

We have an existing Sharepoint Webpart Page. In that page ,we have 2 webparts already. They are "Calendar" WebPart (zone2,zone index1) and "Document" Webpart (zone2,zone index2). Am asked to add a "master list" beneath the "Calender" and "Document". I created a view and populated the "master list" successfully. I tried adding to the Page as webpart and it gets added at the top. But I wanted in the bottom. Am not able to drag n drop. I use IE11 and set on the compatability mode.I minimized and tried drag an drop but in vain.  Am not able to change zone index as they NOT highlighted. I have site owner permission according to my admin. What am I missing above ? Kindly help (yeah,am going crazy). THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit page -> edit webpart -> and in the right side panel that appears set the zone and zone index there.

If you are looking to get the drag and drop working, I've had the same issue when my site wasn't being seen as Intranet as opposed to Internet which changed how compatibility view worked. Make sure that your domain is added to your Intranet Zone sites as http://*.domain.com and https://*.domain.com. Then your compatibility view will actually be used when your site is picked up as intranet zone instead of internet zone.

Comment: Sorry, my zone index is NOT HIGHLIGHTED and I can't change them.

Comment: Its intranet ONLY !